# How to make a good session handling with NHibernate?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, autofac

here I leave my code for a repository pattern with NHibernate and Autofac. I would like to receive some feedback about it. Especially about the session handling with NHibernate. By now I don't like the way that is implemented. Currently the session is created in an IHttpModule on the beginning of the request. Could this session be created with Autofac?.

ISessionModule

```
public class ISessionModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.BeginRequest += context_BeginRequest;
        context.RequestCompleted += context_requestCompleted;
    }
    private void context_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NHibernateHelper.GetCurrentSession();
    }
    private void context_requestCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        NHibernateHelper.CloseSessionFactory();
    }
    public void Dispose()
    {
        //throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Repository class

```
public class BaseRepository<T,TId> : IRepository<T, TId> where T : class
{
    protected ISession session = HttpContext.Current.Items["nhibernate.current_session"] as ISession;
    protected ITransaction transaction = null;
    public BaseRepository()
    {
        //session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession();
        transaction = session.BeginTransaction();
    }
    public async void Create(T entity)
    {
        await session.SaveOrUpdateAsync(entity);
        await transaction.CommitAsync();
    }
    public async void DeleteAsync(TId key)
    {
        var entity = await session.LoadAsync<T>(key);
        await session.DeleteAsync(entity);
        await transaction.CommitAsync();
    }

    public async Task<List<T>> FindAll()
    {
         return await session.Query<T>().ToListAsync();
    }

    public async Task<T> FindOne(TId key)
    {
         return await session.GetAsync<T>(key);
    }

    public async void Update(T entity)
    {
        await session.SaveOrUpdateAsync(entity);
        await transaction.CommitAsync();
    }
}
```

Example of the controller

```
public class ContractsController : ODataController
{
    private readonly BaseRepository<Contract, int> contractRepository;
    public ContractsController(BaseRepository<Contract, int> contractRepository)
    {
        this.contractRepository = contractRepository;
    }
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Get([FromODataUri] int key)
    {
        var contract = await contractRepository.FindOne(key);
        if (contract == null)
        {
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return Ok(contract);
    }
```

Global.asax

```
    public class WebApiApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(BaseRepository<,>)).As(typeof(BaseRepository<,>)).InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
        var container = builder.Build();
        var webApiResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = webApiResolver;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
    }
}
```